# What are the best collaborative ways to edit code? (real time)

Tags: collaboration

Over the shoulder is of course the best, but sometimes we work remotely and want a good way to both edit the same file.

Stuff we've tried:

- Skype screen sharing
- SubEthaEdit
- Google Wave

How do you collaborate in real time environments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [Skywriter](http://mozillalabs.com/skywriter/).